# submitting form is not working using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have form:

```
<form id="search_user" name="search_user" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller/function">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Search" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/content1.js"></script>
```

here is my jquery;

```
$(':submit').submit(function () {
    var linkme = $(this);
    var url = linkme.attr("href");
    $(".content").load(url);

    return false;
});
```

When I press the button submit nothing happens. Please need your advice

Comment: Select the form element. `$('#search_user').submit()`

Comment: /jquery-1.3.2.min.js seriously ? `(':submit')` re... can't you upgrade & look at the latest jquery ways to bind events (delegating with `.on(` )?

Comment: @mikakun: I don't think upgrading jQuery is going to fix this issue. If changing the selector and the use of the correct form attribute (`action`) is fixing it then there is no need to upgrade jQuery just for the sake of it. Even if the elements are injected dynamically it is still possible to bind without `on` with delegation by placing the bindings into the right place. Though I do agree that if starting something new it's always nice to be able to start with the latest jQuery version.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yeah & instead of upgrading jquery & your code "for the sake" of it you can also put in your jq1.3 site : "best viewed with firefox 3.6 & ie6" just in case some crazy internet explorer users are using 8 or 9 or 10 which are part of the reason jquery get upgrades as a matter of fact

Comment: @mikakun: If you don't have any issue with your current application in any browser, don't upgrade for the sake of it if all is well. If you do have issues then upgrade. Don't fix what is not broken. Unless you know OPs exact situation you can't just say "go upgrade". In our current project we have over 30k lines of script, if we would just for giggles upgrade to 1.9 + migrate.js we would probably have no issue but we would have to re-run hundreds of unit tests and sign-off that the upgrade has not broken anything. That is an overhead none of the managers sign-off on just for the sake of it.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl & the more you wait, the biggest the job when finally you have no other choice than the upgrade, the most the rush, the most stressed & unhappy the editor...keeping stuff always on the edge is a silent process; more job yes, bad surprise & unhappy editor no. i'll add that op is dealing with submiting a simple form (if he had thousands of middle age code to manage i'd expect he'd learnt by then how to submit a form with any version of jq)

Comment: Thanks guys I upgraded it to i.9

Answer (score 1):

You have used an incorrect selector `:submit`.

You could subscribe to the submit event of the form using its id and then use the `action` of this form to send an AJAX request:

```
$('#search_user').submit(function() {
    var url = this.action;
    $(".content").load(url); 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: when i try this its the same. when i click submit button nothing happens.